# triggering everyauth login process without page refresh (facebook auth)

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, node.js, everyauth

I've set up `everyauth` and it seems quite nice.

Right now, as illustrated in this [NodeTuts episode](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/26-starting-with-everyauth.html#video), one has to go to `http://www.example.com/auth/facebook` or `http://www.example.com/auth/twitter` in order to authenticate.

How can I configure `everyauth` to allow me to attach a JavaScript event to a button to trigger authentication?

For example, in the following code, the button at the bottom when clicked should popup a Facebook authentication window. How do I do that with everyauth?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe an iframe to one of those urls would work?

Comment: @DTrejo, not a bad idea. Wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I'll suggest you consider the SE model, and look at their page source. They do something very similar.

Comment: @jcolebrand, What is this SE model you refer to? Sorry, I'm not following.

Comment: This network is the StackExchange network. When you login to any StackExchange site they all authenticate against a single authentication server and share the login credentials. That's what you need to do here.

Comment: I don't believe everyauth supports Facebook oauth tokens via the JS SDK, only a server side exchange.  If you want to do that, you'll probably have to go hands on with the everyauth code rather than use it as-is. Modifying oauth code is known to cause migraines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Rob righter's easy-oauth library: https://github.com/robrighter/easy-oauth/blob/master/lib/easy-oauth.js

He inject client-side js and then bypass the route.